# RewriteEngine to hide extensions and GET

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How can I rewrite this URL ?

http://website.com/file.php?lang=en
to
http://website.com/file/en

File name and parameters can change, I found a lot of topics put I did not found the combination of both extensions and GET parameters

Update: I get this to work to hide php extension now how to add the parameters

```
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

# hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

From the code and comment I can say that was one of my answers :P

In order to get this new `http://website.com/file.php?lang=en to http://website.com/file/en` in place have your .htaccess like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php?lang=$2 [L,QSA]

# hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this configuration

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^file/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ file.php?lang=$1
```